# If all geodesics of a connected surface are plane curves, then the surface is contained in a plane or a sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I want to do it in 3 steps:

**1)** If a geodesic is a plane curve, so it is a line of curvature.

**2)** If all curves in a surface are line of curvatures, so all points of $S$ are umbilical.

**3)** If all points in a surface are umbilical, so the surface is contained in a sphere or a plane.

Well, the steps **1)** and **3)** are done, but I really don't know how to do the step **2)**.

I know the definition of umbilical points. It is where $\kappa_{1}=\kappa_{2}$, where $\kappa_{i}$ are the principal curvatures. How can I prove this if the point is contained in a geodesic plane curve (and also a line of curvature, by **1)**)?

Comment: Hello. I would like to know how did you prove 1) I'm having trouble with this same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a point $p$ in $S$ and $w(\neq0) \in T_pS$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and a unique parametrized geodesic curve $\gamma \colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow S$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=w$.
(If you are referring Do Carmo it's in sec. 4.4 prop. 4)

So for a point $p$ in $S$ and for all $w \in T_pS$ there exists a unique geodesic curve which is a principal curve. I think you can draw conclusion from here.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I can't draw a conclusion.
By your argument, for any $p\in S$ and for all $w\in T_{p}S$, exists a unique geodesic (and principal) curve such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=w$, ok. This curve is geodesic, so $\frac{D\gamma'(t)}{dt}(t)=0$ for all $t\in I$, i.e, the vector $\gamma''(t)$ is always normal to the surface $S$. But the curve $\gamma$ is also a principal curve, so $w$ is a principal direction, that is, the directions where the curvature are maximal. How can I conclude that $\kappa_{1}=\kappa_{2}?$

Comment: @MateusRocha It may be late, once we find the geodesic curve, accoring to 1), we know that every direction is the principle direction, which implies that $k_1=k_2$

Comment: Actually, in the second edition, it is sec4.4 prop 5 instead of prop 4