# If $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is connected and every geodesic is planar, then $M$ is contained in a plane or a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

I have seen this question twice on MSE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417342/if-all-geodesics-of-a-connected-surface-are-plane-curves-then-the-surface-is-co) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034710/prove-that-if-all-geodesics-of-a-surface-s-are-planar-curves-then-s-is-cont)), but both questions were considered unanswered by the authors, and the hints there didn't really help me. So I decided to write a new inquiry regarding it.

My idea is to use the following fact to prove that $M$ is totally umbilical, from which the result would follow:

> "If $\alpha$ is a planar geodesic **which is not a line**, then $\alpha$ is a line of curvature"

If $p \in M$ is an arbitrary point, then, given any direction $v \in T_pM$, there exists a unique geodesic going through $p$ with tangent vector $v$ at $p$.

The problem is the part in bold in the above result: if this geodesic is not a line, then the direction is principal.

> But what if, for some direction, the geodesic **IS** a line? How do I deal with that case?

If at least $3$ geodesics are not lines, there are $3$ principal directions, which already means the point is umbilical, I believe. But what about the remaining cases?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Three principal directions or three asymptomatic directions?

Comment: I’d say principal, because lines of curvature are eigenvectors of the weingarten map, and planar non-line geodesic implies line of curvature

Comment: Oh, I misread. You're right. I missed the *not* in front of lines. The issue is to think about the case of lines, which are asymptotic curves. And apologies for auto-correct's inserting *asymptomatic* (humor notwithstanding).